# Problems Connecting to the Internet

Tags: connection, wired

Recently, on my Machine which was running Windows 7 I installed Ubuntu 12.10 using Wubi.exe. Everything else was ok, but problem started when I attempted to connect it to the net. After a bit of hacking around with the answers in this forum I could finally see the message on the top-right hand side- " Wired Network-Connected". But as soon as I open a browser,( which is Mozilla Firefox in my case), I got an error saying -problem loading page. Even though typing in "nm-tool" in the terminal gives me all the details that I set in Manually and says connected. Please help !

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you can see your default gateway, may be you'd better give us your `ifconfig` results.

Comment: you must be able to see your default gateway there, and you must be able to `ping` it